# get more than selected key in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have query regarding selected key in JavaScript.
I am developing a sql query editor a web based application. Here users are required to execute the query using a text box. when they execute a query, the ajax functionality fetches the result and displays them.

Now my requirement is that the query should be executed by pressing key combination of `ctrl+enter`. I know we can achieve keycode of one key, But how for second key ??

the `ctrl+enter` key combination is the same functionality as when we execute query in oracle database.

i.e. on pressing the correct key combination of `ctrl+enter` the query should be executed.

And help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPEHTMLPUBLIC"-//W3C//DTDHTML4.0Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>NewDocument</TITLE>
<METANAME="Generator"CONTENT="EditPlus">
<METANAME="Author"CONTENT="">
<METANAME="Keywords"CONTENT="">
<METANAME="Description"CONTENT="">
<script language="JavaScript">
functionisCtrlEnter(e)
{
    if(window.event){
        if(window.event.ctrlKey&&window.event.keyCode==13){
            //writecodetoclicksomehiddenbutton(useajax)
            alert('isCtrlEnter');
            return false;
        }
    }
else
{
if(e.which==13&&e.ctrlKey){
            //writecodetoclicksomehiddenbutton(useajax)
            alert('isCtrlEnter');
            return false;
            }
}
}
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<input type="text" onkeyup="return isCtrlEnter(event);"/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Apurv....Thanks a lot....It jst worked in a single shot..thanks a lot @Abbas thanks for posting your reply, however i wanted a javascript solution.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you take a look a the jQuery JavaScript library. You can use this snippet to capture a ctrl+enter event:

```
$('#textAreaId').keydown(function (e)
{
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 13)
  {
    alert("ctrl-enter pressed");
  }
});
```